# Turning off multiple WordPress menu items for email addresses

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below function, but don't know how to add multiple email addresses to the list.

```
// Remove Different Admin Menu Links For A Specific User Profile
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
function remove_admin_menu_links(){
     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'user@email.com' == $user->user_email ) {
         remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'page.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=videos' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
     }
 }
 remove_theme_support( 'genesis-admin-menu' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of email addresses and check for their existence:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
function remove_admin_menu_links(){

     $restrictedUsers = [
          "someone@somewhere.com",
          "user@email.com"
     ];

     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && in_array($user->user_email, $restrictedUsers )) {
         remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'page.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=videos' );
         remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
     }
 }
 remove_theme_support( 'genesis-admin-menu' );
```

Comment: Thank you! There is just a missing closing bracket on the if statement. Other than that, it's working well.